# Lista ul scrollable con sub lista

Tags: html, css

Buenas estoy intentando hacer que mi lista ul contenga scroll ya que el contenido de la misma es mas grande que la ventana, la propiedad overflow la seteo perfectamente, mi problema esta en que no hace la apertura de la sub items dejo imagenes debajo para ilustrar el problema, el menu header donde esta contenido es fixed por este motivo no puedo usar el scroll de la ventana de la web, dejo una una muestra del codigo HTML debajo[image: Lista ul desplegable sin scroll]
[image: Lista ul desplegable con scroll no hace apertura de los subitems]

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav top-main-menu menu-categories" style="height: 45px;">
                    <li class="leaf has-sub links-gris-ul-cat" style="color:#5f5d5d;">
                        <span class="">Categorías</span>
                        
<ul class="menu menu-list catalog-categories catalog-categories-tree" style="
    overflow: scroll;
">
          <li>
        <a href="n-accesorios/" title="Accesorios">
    <span class="category-label">Accesorios</span>
      <span class="icon-triangle"></span>
  </a>

                  
<ul class="menu menu-list sublevel with-menu-banner" style="height: 1001px;">
          <li class="leaf">
        <a href="n-accesorios/accesorios/" title="Accesorios">
      <span class="category-menu-icon">
<img src="" alt="" height="30" width="30" data-max-width="30" data-max-height="30" data-is-default-image="" srcset="">
</span>
    <span class="category-label">Accesorios</span>
  </a>

              </li>
          <li class="leaf active">
        <a href="n-accesorios/billeteras-y-monederos/" title="Billeteras y Monederos">
      <span class="category-menu-icon">
<img src="" alt="" height="30" width="30" data-max-width="30" data-max-height="30" data-is-default-image="" srcset="">
</span>
    <span class="category-label">Billeteras y Monederos</span>
  </a>

              </li>
       
       
                    <li class="categories-menu-banner-wrapper">
        <div class="categories-menu-banner">
            
<img src="" alt="" height="230" width="230" data-max-width="230" data-max-height="500" data-is-default-image="">

        </div>
    </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar `overflow-y: scroll` para solo aplicar el scrollbar en el eje vertical. Asegurate de tener `overflow-x:visible;` en el mismo elemento, para que la expansión de los hijos (desplegandose a la derecha) sea posible.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, con la propiedad overflow-x:visible no se genera la apertura lateral expansión de los hijos, otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: tendría que ver el resto del código involucrado (CSS, JS), tienes un codepen o similar con el codigo para mirarlo en acción?